# ARDUINO / PYTHON / SERIAL

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, serial-port

I need a little help to make my code work correctly. The following will be the arduino and python codes.

What I need to happen is that when I put my face on, the green LED lights up, meaning it's released! If an unregistered face appears, the red led will light up. But I think my code is not correct.

PYTHON CODE

```
import face_recognition as fr
import os
import serial

porta_serial = serial.Serial('COM3',9600)

encoders = []
nomes = []

def criarEncoders():
    lista = os.listdir('Pessoas')
    for arquivo in lista:
        imAtual = fr.load_image_file(f'Pessoas/{arquivo}')
        imAtual = cv2.cvtColor(imAtual,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encoders.append(fr.face_encodings(imAtual)[0])
        nomes.append(os.path.splitext(arquivo)[0])

def compararWebcam():
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        check,img = video.read()
        imgP = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)

        imgP = cv2.cvtColor(imgP,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        try:
            faceLoc = fr.face_locations(imgP)[0]
        except:
            faceLoc = []

        if faceLoc:
            y1,x2,y2,x1 = faceLoc
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1*4, x2*4, y2*4, x1*4
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)  # criando o retângulo em volta da face na webcam com a cor verde
            porta_serial.write(b'o')
            encodeImg = fr.face_encodings(imgP)[0]

            for id,enc in enumerate(encoders):             # loop para comparar imagem com o banco de dados
                comp = fr.compare_faces([encodeImg],enc)
                if comp[0]:
                    cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y2-35),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),-1)
                    cv2.putText(img,nomes[id],(x1+6,y2-6),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(255,255,255),2)
                    porta_serial.write(b'f')
                    print(nomes[id])

        cv2.imshow('Webcam', img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

criarEncoders()
compararWebcam()
```

ARDUINO CODE

```
int led_liberado = 8;
int led_nao_liberado = 7;
char var;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led_liberado, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_nao_liberado, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led_nao_liberado, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    if (var=='o') {
      digitalWrite(led_liberado, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(led_nao_liberado, LOW);
    } else if(var=='f') {
      digitalWrite(led_nao_liberado,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(led_liberado, LOW);
    } else if (var=='q') {
      digitalWrite(led_nao_liberado, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(led_liberado, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Learn crawing before learning walking. Started with making one part of your code work first. 1) Your Arduino code doesn't read anything from serial port (missing `Serial.read()`). 2) your eyes won't be able to see the LED blinking if you turning on an LED with `digitalWrite(led_librado, HIGH)` then immediate turning it off with `digitalWrite(led_librado, LOW)`, you need to add some delay in between. 3) For python code, I don't see anywhere you send data via serial port to Arduino. So start with writing some simple code to send the commands to Arduino first before tackling facial recognition.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture it has something to do with this line.

```
y1,x2,y2,x1 = faceLoc
y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1*4, x2*4, y2*4, x1*4
#If (x1,y1),(x2,y2) indicate some coordinate of where a face is which seems like it, multiplying them by a scalar loses that information?
#Consider your ROI is at (2,2) and your function grids it at (1,1),(3,3).
#Your code would then change the rectangle to (4,4),(12,12) 
#which doesnt even contain your point of interest. Meaning...no face?
```

Of course this is just conjencture. You would probably still need to debug every aspect of your code. 1) Arduino commands 2) Python to Arduino interface 3) Face recognition function 4) Transforms and image stuff